# Python 2to3 not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2to3

I'm currently going through the python challenge, and i'm up to level 4, [see here](http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/linkedlist.php) I have only been learning python for a few months, and i'm trying to learn python 3 over 2.x so far so good, except when i use this bit of code, here's the python 2.x version:

```
import urllib, re
prefix = "http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/linkedlist.php?nothing="
findnothing = re.compile(r"nothing is (\d+)").search
nothing = '12345'
while True:
    text = urllib.urlopen(prefix + nothing).read()
    print text
    match = findnothing(text)
    if match:
        nothing = match.group(1)
        print "   going to", nothing
    else:
        break
```

So to convert this to 3, I would change to this:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error, re
prefix = "http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/linkedlist.php?nothing="
findnothing = re.compile(r"nothing is (\d+)").search
nothing = '12345'
while True:
    text = urllib.request.urlopen(prefix + nothing).read()
    print(text)
    match = findnothing(text)
    if match:
        nothing = match.group(1)
        print("   going to", nothing)
    else:
        break
```

So if i run the 2.x version it works fine, goes through the loop, scraping the url and goes to the end, i get the following output:

```
and the next nothing is 72198
   going to 72198
and the next nothing is 80992
   going to 80992
and the next nothing is 8880
   going to 8880 etc
```

If i run the 3.x version, i get the following output:

```
b'and the next nothing is 44827'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\lvl4.py", line 26, in <module>
    match = findnothing(b"text")
TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

So if i change the r to a b in this line

```
findnothing = re.compile(b"nothing is (\d+)").search
```

I get:

```
b'and the next nothing is 44827'
   going to b'44827'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\lvl4.py", line 24, in <module>
    text = urllib.request.urlopen(prefix + nothing).read()
TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
```

Any ideas?

I'm pretty new to programming, so please don't bite my head off.

_bk201

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't mix bytes and str objects implicitly.

The simplest thing would be to decode bytes returned by `urlopen().read()` and use str objects everywhere:

```
text = urllib.request.urlopen(prefix + nothing).read().decode() #note: utf-8
```

The page doesn't specify the preferable character encoding via `Content-Type` header or `<meta>` element. I don't know what the default encoding should be for `text/html` but the [rfc 2068 says](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2068#page-26):

> When no explicit charset parameter is provided by the sender, media
> subtypes of the "text" type are defined to have a default charset
> value of "ISO-8859-1" when received via HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions make sense only on text, not on binary data.
So, keep `findnothing = re.compile(r"nothing is (\d+)").search`, and convert `text` to string instead.

Comment: Thankyou also! this does make a lot of sense.

Comment: You can apply regular expressions on bytes, but the pattern should also be bytes in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `urllib` we're using `requests` and it has two options ( which maybe you can search in urllib for similar options )

Response object

```
import requests
>>> response = requests.get('https://api.github.com')
```

Using `response.content` - has the `bytes` type

```
>>> response.content
b'{"current_user_url":"https://api.github.com/user","current_us...."}'
```

While using `response.text` - you have the encoded response

```
>>> response.text
'{"current_user_url":"https://api.github.com/user","current_us...."}'
```

The default encoding is `utf-8`, but you can set it right after the request like so

```
import requests
>>> response = requests.get('https://api.github.com')
>>> response.encoding = 'SOME_ENCODING'
```

And then `response.text` will hold the content in the encoding you requested ...